# Regex to catch <strong >strong</strong >

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex expression to catch the `< strong >` and `< /strong >` around the text (`< strong > text < /strong >`, however I want to avoid removing the text in the middle of the `< strong >` and `< /strong >`

Basically after

```
preg_replace($expression, "", "<strong>STRONG</strong>");
```

would just give me `STRONG` without the `< strong >` and `< /strong >`

I currently have:

```
<\w*>\w*<\/\w*>
```

however; this catches the text bewteen the tags too.

Comment: unclear for me. Could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: Yeah sorry @AvinashRaj,

string: "<strong>Hello</strong>" and I want just "Hello", it's for an exercise so I'd normally use the strip_tags function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
<\/?strong>
```

The command:

```
preg_replace("/<\/?strong>/", "", "<strong>Hello</strong>");
```

[**Online demo**](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/9qX)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the text you don't want to remove in a capture group:

```
<\w*>(\w*)</\w*>
```

and replace with `$1` to avoid removing the captured text.

Or, you can use the pattern

```
</?\w*>
```

to match only the opening and closing tags, without the text inbetween. This will, however, remove stray tags without a corresponding opening/closing tag too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip only opening and closing tag for strong then that should be enough:

```
$out = preg_replace(array('$\\<\s?strong\s?\\>$si', '$\\</\s?strong\s?\\>$si'), '', "<strong>STRONG</strong>");
```